# live reload not working for php files in vs code

Tags: php, visual-studio, localhost

I've installed the `live server` extension on VS code and on google chrome, and configure them to enable live reload but live reload is not working. It was working a few hours ago but now I can't get it to work.
[image]

My server I'm using
[image]

live server:
[image]

Things I've tried:

- deleting and reinstalling both live servers
- quitting VS code
- made sure live server was turned on in VS code.

Comment: I recommend try searching on youtube try this. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jdWlGQdq1Q0

Comment: For anyone tempted to click on that link from the @user8486381 posted above, I will save you some time. It is useless and has nothing to do with PHP, and in no way does it answer the OP's question.

Comment: [Here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/live-server-web-extension/fiegdmejfepffgpnejdinekhfieaogmj) is the chrome extension and [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) the vscode one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are not running another localhost website somewhere, live server can only reload one website at a time.

Answer (score 0):

In my case all below steps helped:

-change settings in VS Code. If you go to Settings, search for these options and set them as below:

Live Server Settings:
Custom Browser: chrome (I use chrome, you can choose yours of course)
Full Reload:  yes, you should mark it
Port: 0
Use Web Ext: unmark it
Wait: 3

Settings:
autosave: afterDelay

-check if your HTML file name is correct (without special signs etc) and if there is utf-8 in 
-I also installed extension in my Chrome browser ("LiveReload")- you can download it in GoogleStore.

Save all changes, reopen chrome and VsCode and check if it works.